# Add and/or Remove Class from a form Element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a jQuery script that will add a class when the user is focused on the form element and when the user leaves the form element, the class is removed.

```
$("#search_text").click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('search').addClass('search_active');
    $('#search_icon').removeClass('search_icon').addClass('search_icon_active');
});
```

This script adds the class, but does not remove it when the user has the left the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said by Daniel A. White, you should use `.focus` and `.blur`

```
$("#search_text").focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('search').addClass('search_active');
    $('#search_icon').removeClass('search_icon').addClass('search_icon_active');
});

$("#search_text").blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('search_active').addClass('search');
    $('#search_icon').removeClass('search_icon_active').addClass('search_icon');
});
```

For more information on:
Focus: http://api.jquery.com/focus/
Blur: http://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: unfortinatelly I use this to fieldset and 'focus' , 'blur' do not work in my case, with click all OK! so wiil be cool if someone can help with click idea!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `.focus` and `.blur` jquery events.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind excluding IE 6 and 7 you can use the :focus CSS event.

```
input { background-color: #F7F7F7; }
input:focus { background-color: #FFFFFF; }
```